# How to display training progress bar in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to output to the terminal the same type of training progress bar that is done with Keras training.  I'm new to tensorflow and have not yet tried Keras, but I'm interested in knowing if it can be done without Keras.

Answer (score 14):

```
import tensorflow as tf
train_data = (...) 
progbar = tf.keras.utils.Progbar(len(train_data))

for i, d in enumerate(train_data):
    (train model here...)
    progbar.update(i) # This will update the progress bar graph.


3714/3715 [============================>.] - ETA: 20s
```

- In Tensorflow (v1.1~ 2.1), it is recommended to use `tf.keras.utils.Progbar()` instead of importing `tqdm`.
- FYI, use `tf.print()`, instead of python native print function.

Comment: cleaner version: 
progbar = tf.keras.utils.Progbar(len(list(train_data.as_numpy_iterator())))...................
 
for i, d in train_data.enumerate(start=1):....................

progbar.update(i)

Answer (score 5):

Maybe I don't fully understand your `training progress bar`'s meaning:
But I think you can try a python package:`tqdm`, put it into your `training loop`:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
for i in tqdm(range(10000)):
    ...
```

then you will get something like that:

```
100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [00:00<00:00, 1383300.02it/s]
```

There is `tqdm`'s doc. https://tqdm.github.io/.

Comment: This worked great!  Thank you very much for the guidance!

Comment: Haha, It's good, and maybe you can accept the answer if you want~ @Bill

Comment: Does the tqdm progress bar integrate well with the @tf.function decorator in TensorFlow 2? I am thinking tf.keras.util.Progbar is probably the way to go.

Comment: @MattSt No. That's why we should avoid importing tqdm directly.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's possible.

```
model.fit(X, y, nb_epoch=40, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.2, verbose=0)
```

verbose: 0 for no logging to stdout, 1 for progress bar logging, 2 for one log line per epoch.

Comment: Thanks but this looks like it is for keras if I'm not mistaken.  The previous tqdm solution works for tensorflow without keras.