# How to customize the printed text in TensorFlow Keras progress bar?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, progress-bar

Is it possible to customize the text appearning in TensorFlow's Keras progress bar?
My current implementation and usage is the following (I use TensorFlow 2.8):

```
bar = tf.keras.utils.Progbar(target=n_train_samples)
step = 0
for x in dataset:
  train_step(x)
  step += 1
  bar.update(step * batch_size)
```

And the current behavior is:

```
 48/316 [===>..........................] - ETA: 1:19
```

However, I would like to print something like:

```
 TRAIN: 48/316 [===>..........................] - ETA: 1:19
```

---

**Edit:** I have also tried to print text before the progress bar, but then it gets overwritten. E.g. the code below:

```py
import time
import tensorflow as tf

bar = tf.keras.utils.Progbar(target=10)
step = 0
for x in range(10):
    time.sleep(0.2)
    step += 1
    print("TRAIN: ", end="")
    bar.update(step)
```

returns the following output:

```
10/10 [==============================] - 5s 501ms/step
```

---

**What I don't want to happen:** I don't want to have prints on multiple lines. The progress bar should still update itself on the same line, just pre-appending "TRAIN" to it. So, at time step #3, I don't want:

```
 TRAIN: 
 1/10 [==>...........................] - ETA: 4s
 TRAIN: 
 2/10 [=====>........................] - ETA: 4s
 TRAIN: 
 3/10 [========>.....................] - ETA: 3s
```

but I want:

```
 TRAIN: 3/10 [========>.....................] - ETA: 3s
```

Comment: You can attach a print statement  inside for loop. Attaching relevant thread for reference. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57971007/tensorflow-2-0-display-progress-bar-in-custom-training-loop

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. Yes, I had though of it, but then the two prints would be on different lines, while I'd like to have them on the same line. I have tried to do `print("TRAIN: ", end="")`, but then as the progress bar proceeds printing the `"TRAIN: "` text disappears. Do you know any workaround for this?

Comment: Definitely!Could you please share a complete reproducible code with the above error?

Comment: Code added :) I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Resolved Code:

```
import time import tensorflow as tf

bar = tf.keras.utils.Progbar(target=10) step = 0

for x in range(10):
    print("\n TRAIN: ")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    step += 1
    bar.update(step)
```

Output:

```
TRAIN: 
 1/10 [==>...........................] - ETA: 4s
 TRAIN: 
 2/10 [=====>........................] - ETA: 4s
 TRAIN: 
 3/10 [========>.....................] - ETA: 3s
 TRAIN: 
 4/10 [===========>..................] - ETA: 3s
 TRAIN: 
 5/10 [==============>...............] - ETA: 2s
 TRAIN: 
 6/10 [=================>............] - ETA: 2s
 TRAIN: 
 7/10 [====================>.........] - ETA: 1s
 TRAIN: 
 8/10 [=======================>......] - ETA: 1s
 TRAIN: 
 9/10 [==========================>...] - ETA: 0s
 TRAIN: 
10/10 [==============================] - 5s 503ms/step
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your kind reply, but I was looking for a solution allowing me to have the printed "TRAIN" on the same line as the progress bar. In fact, your solution has the drawback of having a progress bar that does not overwrite itself (i.e. you have multiple lines, but I would like to have only one line updating in time). I'm updating my question to better reflect my needs

Comment: Yeah. You can put the print statement before for a loop . Keeping the "Train" word in line with training logs might not be possible due to space constraint. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just print something with a few spaces in front and no LF in end. It'll save until overwritten, which is probably never.

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
saveTime = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")  # userfriendly now
print("        saved at ", saveTime, end='', flush=True)


Epoch: 3
21/98 [=====>........................] - ETA: 16:04 - total_loss: 83.5692 - rec_loss: 0.0669 - perc_loss: 0.7274 - smooth_loss: 0.2739 - warping_loss: 0.6828 - psnr: 19.1418 - ssim: 0.5147        saved at  12:22:03
```

Also, take note of your screen width.